# CGAffineTransform animation not ending in correct position

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I'm applying a translation to a `UILabel` that should result in the label ending at the same x position where it began, but it seems to hang left for some reason.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.1 initialSpringVelocity:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

    NSLog(@"PLAYLABEL BEGIN X %f", self.playLabel.frame.origin.x);

    self.playLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-10, 0);
    self.playLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(+20, 0);
    self.playLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-10, 0);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    NSLog(@"PLAYLABEL DONE X %f", self.playLabel.frame.origin.x);

}];
```

The origin.x of the label before the animation is 119.500000 and on completion the origin.x is 109.500000.  Am I wrong about how the translation is being applied?  If I transform -10 from the origin, then transform +20 from its current position, then the label should only be +10 from the origin.  Therefore -10, should result in label.x to be where it originally was.

Answer (score 1):

`CGAffineTransformMake` creates a transformation matrix. It looks like you're thinking the 3 matrices you create are applied sequentially. However, you are overwriting the matrix twice. When animate duration is called, it applies `self.playlabel.transform`, which is equal to the last time you set it: `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-10, 0);`

Comment: I see what you're saying.  However, the animation is working exactly like I want it to (wobbles left to right).  The label moves left 10, moves right 20, but ends -10 from the origin.  Whats a better way to get this done?

Comment: I would prefer using a uibezierpath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538279/moving-an-object-along-a-curve-in-iphone-development  You can use this code, but just change the view and the points.

Comment: Use the bezier path, its a better solution. But if you want playlabel to end it its original location, set its transform to cgaffinetransformidentity

Comment: @Nick i tried `cgaffinetransformidentity` but the animation doesn't occur at all.  If I use the bezier path route, can I still use the spring damping and velocity animation options?  The example uses a `CAKeyframeAnimation` so I don't know if I can get the same effect I'm looking for.

Comment: One work around (that I am not particularly fond of) is to chain the animations.  So add in another animateWithDuration in the completion block: http://ios.robertlinnemann.com/chaining-uiview-animations-with-blocks/.